# While inserting the data in oracle 12C i am getting java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long

Tags: oracle

While inserting the data in oracle `12C` i am getting below error ->
`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric` or `value error:` raw variable length too long.

Please help me.

Comment: use this for detailed error logs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-jan/o14plsql-2045346.html

Comment: Try your luck here https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06502.php

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question and the code that inserts the data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question do **not** post code in comments